# Why does xargs strip quotes from input?

Tags: xargs

Why does xargs strip quotes from input text?

Here is a simplified example:

```
echo "/Place/='http://www.google.com'" | xargs echo
```

outputs

```
/Place/=http://www.google.com
```

Is there any way to work-around this?
(xargs -0 doesn't help me)

Comment: `xargs` treats quotes and backslashes specially as part of the [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html).  Post what you are trying to do with `xargs` instead.

Comment: `xargs -0` works for me here... Why doesn't it help you?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the `xargs` manual:

> If you want an input argument to contain blanks or horizontal tabs, enclose it in double quotes or apostrophes. If the argument contains a double quote character (`"`), you must enclose the argument in apostrophes. Conversely, if the argument contains an apostrophe (`'`), you must enclose the argument in double quotes. You can also put a backslash (`\`) in front of a character to tell xargs to ignore any special meaning the character may have (for example, white space characters, or quotes).

This means you can escape quotes if the quotes are quoted themselves:

```
$ echo "/Place/=\'http://www.google.com\'" | xargs echo
/Place/='http://www.google.com'
```

will work but `echo /Place/=\'http://www.google.com\' | xargs echo` will not.

Comment: Nothing against down votes but a comment on the reason would help :-)

Comment: What if you're piping in input? If I have a script that outputs `"/Place/='http://www.google.com'"`, how can I properly escape it?

Comment: @RogerFilmyer your_script | parallel --shellquote | ...

Answer (score 38):

if you want `xargs` to **ignore quotes** one of the good soultion can be the use of `xargs` flag **xargs -0**

> Directly from Man page OPTIONS
>
> OPTIONS     -0, --null
>
> Input items are terminated by a null character instead of by whitespace, and the quotes and backslash are not special (every character is taken literally).
>                 Disables the end of file string, which is treated like any other argument.  Useful when input items might contain white space, quote marks, or backslashes.
>                 The GNU find -print0 option produces input suitable for this mode.

I've checked on a GNU system that setting the delimiter to a specific value (like a newline) with `-d` option (and not just `-0`) would also cause `xargs` not to treat the quotes etc specially:

```
-bash-4.3$ { echo "a'b'c"; echo d; } | xargs -d$'\n' echo
a'b'c d
-bash-4.3$ rpm -qf "$(which xargs)"
findutils-4.6.0.0.99.11a05-alt1.x86_64
-bash-4.3$ { echo "a'b'c"; echo d; } | xargs echo
abc d
-bash-4.3$
```

Comment: This answer suggests using `-0` but goes ahead to given an example using `-d` instead. `-d` as called out by the other answers works on GNU only, and `-0` only works if the input can be provided with a NUL delimiter.

Answer (score 28):

For GNU xargs, I found another solution in the manpage: explicitly specify delimiter to be '\n'. This turns off special handling for quotes:

> --delimiter=delim, -d delim
>
> Input items are terminated by the specified character.  The
> specified delimiter may be a single character, a C-style character escape such  as \n, or an octal or hexadecimal escape code.  Octal and hexadecimal escape codes are understood as for the printf command.   Multibyte characters are not supported.  When processing the input, quotes
> and backslash are not special; every character in the input is taken literally.

So,

```
echo "/Place/='http://www.google.com'" | xargs -d'\n' echo
```

outputs

```
/Place/='http://www.google.com'
```

Comment: Note that it implies GNU `xargs` or compatible

Comment: Also note that it also stops space and tab from being recognised as delimiters (probably just as well in the OP's case).

Comment: [Balman gave a similar solution](/a/361330) (well [actually @imz](/revisions/361330/3)) though yours is somewhat better in that it avoids the use of the `ksh93` `$'...'` quoting operator that is not found in every shell implementation.

Comment: I found this helpful again, but I cannot upvote again...

Answer (score 10):

You could use GNU Parallel instead:

```
$ echo "/Place/='http://www.google.com'" | parallel echo
/Place/='http://www.google.com'
```

Then you do not have to do the quoting yourself.

Learn more: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Answer (score 8):

I found another solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17468560/1795821 that suggests using `sed` to escape quotes.

For example:

```
sh-3.2$ echo "/Place/='http://www.google.com'" | sed "s/\'/\\\'/g" | xargs echo
/Place/='http://www.google.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

From others answer one importation aspect is missing.
"strip quotes" is not accurate description what `xargs` do.
Better would be say its "evaluate" quotes similar how normal
`bash` handling do:

```bash
echo "'a "'"'"a' "'"'"a b"'"'" '\\' \\\"a b\\\" " | xargs -n1 echo
```

output:

```
a "a
a b
\
"a
b"
```

And for "raw" output:

```bash
echo "'a "'"'"a' "'"'"a b"'"'" '\\' \\\"a b\\\" " | xargs -d$'\n' -n1 echo
```

output:

```
'a "a' "a b" '\' \"a b\"
```

As we see some `"` get processed where other `"` will not be changed.
This mean adding random `\` to escape input will butcher nested quotes.
This mean is better to disable quote processing in `xargs` than trying to work around it.