# How to quote arguments with xargs

Tags: shell, find, quoting, rm, xargs

Suppose that I want to delete all files in a folder that are greater than 1 MB.

```
$ find . -size +1M | xargs -0 rm
```

This will not delete files that have space in their names. So I want it to quote all arguments it sends to `rm`. If `find` gives it `Some report.docx` it should pass `"Some report.docx"` to `rm`.

How can I do that?

Comment: You should read this http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind?highlight=%28xargs%29  before doing anything with `xargs`. Also as the wiki suggests, don't use `xargs` without passing the `-print0` to `find`.

Comment: More generally, see [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: Use `xargs -d$'\n'` to limit the delimiter to only new lines (and not spaces; this wouldn't [process quotes etc. specially](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38148/4319) -- I've checked on a GNU system) -- the answer given in http://stackoverflow.com/a/33528111/94687

Comment: Related: [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Comment: See [Search for text files where two different words exist (any order, any line)](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/67820) for the length you have to  go to transform file paths into the format expected by `xargs` without the `-0` option.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As you're already using that non-standard `1M`, chances are your `find` implementation also supports `-delete`. So, simply use:

```
find . -type f -size +1M -delete
```

Where supported, that's by far the safest and most efficient.

If you insist on using `xargs` and `rm` with `find`, just add `-print0` in your command:

```
find . -type f -size +1M -print0 | xargs -r0 rm -f --
```

(`-print0` and `-0` are non-standard, but pretty common. `-r` (to avoid running `rm` at all if `find` doesn't find anything) is less common, but if your `xargs` doesn't support it, you can just omit it, as `rm` with `-f` won't complain if called without argument).

The standard syntax would be:

```
find . -type f -size +1048576c -exec rm -f -- {} +
```

Other way:

```
find . -type f -size +1M -execdir rm -f -- {} +
```

(that's safer than `-exec`/`xargs -0` and would work with very deep directory trees (where full file paths would end up larger than `PATH_MAX`), but that's also non-standard, and runs at least one `rm` for each directory that contains at least one big file, so would be less efficient).

From [`man find`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) on a GNU system:

> **`-print0`**
>
> True; print the full file name on the standard output, followed by a null
> character (instead of the newline character that `-print` uses). This allows file names
> that contain newlines or other types of white space to be correctly interpreted by
> programs that process the `find` output. This option corresponds to the `-0` option of
> `xargs`.

Comment: This solves the problem but actually quoting the arguments would be useful in other cases. So I'll hold on for other answers. +1 for a simple solution though.

Comment: @KshitizSharma No, you do not want to pass `"Some report.docx"` to `rm`, unless the file name contains the quotes. What you want is to pass `Some report.docx` unmolested to `rm`. KasiyA's answer (now) shows the general way to do that with `find`. [KasiyA: sorry for the wrong ping earlier.]

Comment: @Gilles Correct. In bash I generally quote the string to pass it unmolested. So by quoting what I meant was to send filename as a single argument to rm instead of being split up into `$0` and `$1` etc.

Comment: On OSX I do `xargs -0` instead of `xargs -r0`.

Answer (score 50):

I had a similar requirement and ended up using the `-I` switch to have a placeholder and I was able to quote it.

```
find . -size +1M | xargs -I {} rm "{}"
```

Comment: With `xargs -I`, you'll still have problems with filenames that contain single quotes, double quotes, backslashes or newlines (leading blanks are also a problem, but with the output of `find .`, that can only occur for filenames that contain `<newline><blanks>`).

Comment: Quoting that second `{}` makes absolutely no difference here. That's just quoting for the shell, and that `{}` doesn't need quoting in most shells. As far as `xargs` is concerned, it receives an argument containing `{}` (the two characters `{` and `}`) for both the `{}` after `-I` and `"{}"` after `rm`. It is exactly the same as `xargs -I {} rm {}` or `xargs -I "{}" rm '{}'`

Comment: Just escape the quotes like this:

`find . -size +1M | xargs -I {} rm \"{}\"`

Comment: It simply don't work. It gets only the first element (tested with `tar`). See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/635479/41011 instead

Answer (score 15):

Option `-0` of `xargs` means that output from pipe is interpreted as null terminated items. In such case you also need to create input for the pipe with `find ... -print0`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple way to do it that does not rely on special flags in `find`. It works for any input into `xargs`. Just use `sed` to wrap each line in quotes.

```
find . -size +1M | sed 's/.*/"&"/' | xargs ls -l
```

You can replace `ls -l` with `rm` after you are satisfied it works.

Comment: With `sed 's/.*/"&"/'` quoting, you'll still have problems with filenames that contain `"` or newline characters or sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters in the locale.

Comment: Stéphane: Good catch regarding the `-delete` and double quotes in file name. I have removed the `-delete`. Regarding escaping quotes it needs a more robust sed expression. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this? I’ll think about it.

Comment: See for instance: [Search for text files where two different words exist (any order, any line)](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/67820)

Answer (score 2):

Actually just reiterating an existing comment to the question so that it appears under answers, in my case I was using `locate` to find filenames containing a certain string:

Ivan Zakharyaschev wrote: *Use `xargs -d$'\n'` to limit the delimiter to only new lines (and not spaces; this [wouldn't process quotes etc. specially](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38148/4319) -- I've checked on a GNU system) -- the answer given in
[stackoverflow.com/a/33528111/94687](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33528111/94687)*

So for example using Ivan's suggestion,

```
$ locate -i example_string | xargs -d$'\n' md5sum
```