# Wildcard to match mypackage*.tar.xz but not mypackage*fast.tar.xz?

Tags: linux, shell-script, wildcards

Before building my project I wish to delete any prexisting binaries in the directory. Now this directory contains two files `mypackage-<version>-fast.tar.xz` and `mypackage-<version>.tar.xz`. I wish to delete only the `mypackage-<version>.tar.xz` and not the `*fast.tar.xz` file.

Running `rm mypackage-*.tar.xz` deletes both the files whereas `find . -type f ! -name *fast.tar.xz` lists other source files in the directory which I don't want to be deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the version of your package always ends with a digit, you could use

```
rm mypackage-*[0-9].tar.xz
```

... or you could use some similar way to match the end of the version number that excludes the match of the `-fast` variant of the package (maybe even just `mypackage-*[!t].tar.xz`).

If this is not possible, then...

Assuming that you are using a shell, such as `bash`, which allows the use of extended `ksh`-style globbing patterns (enabled with `shopt -s extglob` in `bash`), you could do

```
rm mypackage-!(*-fast).tar.xz
```

The `!(*-fast)` portion of the filename globbing pattern above would match any string except strings that match `*-fast`.

This would also work in the `zsh` shell, if its `KSH_GLOB` shell option is set (`setopt KSH_GLOB`). With `zsh` extended globbing enabled (`setopt EXTENDED_GLOB`), you could instead use

```
rm mypackage-^(*-fast).tar.xz
```

To additionally only delete regular files, add the glob qualifier `(.)` to the very end of that filename globbing pattern.

In a `sh` shell, you could use

```
for name in mypackage-*.tar.xz; do
    case $name in (mypackage-*-fast.tar.xz) ;; (*) rm "$name"; esac
done
```

or,

```
for name in mypackage-*.tar.xz; do
    case $name in (mypackage-*-fast.tar.xz) continue; esac
    rm "$name"
done
```

This iterates over all names that matches `mypackage-*.tar.xz`, skips the names that additionally matches `mypackage-*-fast.tar.xz`, and deletes the rest.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the find command, but need to specify the query more:

```
find . -type f -name 'mypackage-*.tar.xz' ! -name 'mypackage-*fast.tar.xz'
```

Then you can use the `-delete` action in many versions of find to remove the found files:

```
find . -type f -name 'mypackage-*.tar.xz' ! -name 'mypackage-*fast.tar.xz' -delete
```

Comment: `xargs` can be a bit of a pain if the filenames contain spaces or quotes, [by default it treats both specially](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38148/170373). find can delete the files itself, either with `find -delete` or `find -exec rm -- {} +`

Comment: You may want to add `-maxdepth 1` to stop `find` from deleting files from subdirectories.

Comment: The -maxdepth bit helps because I had saved older binaries in a backup subdirectory.