# Converting multiline to single line in a file looses double quotes

Tags: files, quoting, text-formatting, newlines

Here is my sample file

```
cat test.txt
"IND WEB",
"Speed Web (Internal webserver)",
"Web Bill",
```

I tried the below two solutions to convert multiline to single line however the double quotes `"` are lost !!

```
cat listofapps.txt | xargs -s 8192
IND WEB, Speed Web (Internal webserver), Web Bill,

tr '\n' < listofapps.txt
IND WEB, Speed Web (Internal webserver), Web Bill,
```

Can you please suggest so that the double quotes remain ?

Comment: Please check that the information in your question accurately reflects what you tried (`tr '\n' < listofapps.txt` isn't a valid command for example - did you mean `tr -d '\n' < listofapps.txt` ?)

Comment: ... and for the `xargs` because quotes are special to `xargs`  [Why does xargs strip quotes from input?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38148/why-does-xargs-strip-quotes-from-input)

Comment: @steeldriver `tr -d '\n' < listofapps.txt` works !! thank you. I was missing the `-d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `xargs`, the double quotes are lost because they are being interpreted by the `xargs` utility (see [Why does xargs strip quotes from input?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38148)).

Your `tr` command is broken and ought to have given you an error message.

To delete newlines with `tr`, use

```
tr -d '\n' <file
```

To replace the newlines with spaces, use

```
tr '\n' ' ' <file
```

To join the lines with spaces:

```
paste -sd ' ' file
```

(same as above, except that it adds a newline in the end to make it one valid line of text).

Answer (score 0):

`sed` way:

```
sed '${G;s/\n//g;p;};H;d' sample.txt
```

The same, but with explanation in comment:

```
sed '
    ${
        # If we are in the last line

        G; # Get anything stored in the hold space

        s/\n//g; # Replace any occurrence of space with nothing

        p; # Print 
    }
   
    # We are not in the last line so 
    H; # save the current line
    d; # and start the next cycle without print
' sample.txt
```

Comment: @Kusalananda, (re: your edit). That still doesn't make it portable as there's nothing allowed after `}` in standard `sed` syntax. It would have to be `sed -e '${G;s/\n//g;p;}' -e 'H;d'` but even then as the whole file ends up in the pattern space, POSIX doesn't give you any warrantee for anything but short files. `sed` is not the best tool for the task here.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You are correct, but at least my native OpenBSD `sed` can grok it with no errors. So it's _better_ now.  The fact that the code reads the whole file into memory is an issue that is part of the original answer.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser It's a sample, put together for the question.